# Sending a CTRL B with java

Tags: java, telnet

I am talking to a device via a Telnet connection (Telnet client from Apache), the device requires us to send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to go into a certain mode. How can I send that via Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is just the byte `2`.

Given an `OutputStream out`, `out.write(2);`.

Function keys and the like will have escape sequences, exactly what sequence is determined by which terminal you have negotiated to emulate.